# React SVG disappearing when component rerenders

Tags: javascript, reactjs, dom, svg

I am making a react application with some SVG icons within my components. For instance, I have a SearchBar component which includes the input element along with a button that has a Search Icon in it.

I am using inline SVG for all my SVG icons, by setting the xlinkHref attribute accordingly from a single sprite file.

Everything seems to work just fine, except that my SVG icons randomly disappear when I click on them. The button element that contains the icon does not disappear, just the SVG icon. I checked the DOM tree on the devtools, and it seems like that there is an issue with a node called "#shadow-root".

When my SVG icons are visible, they are placed as child nodes of the "#shadow-root". However, when they disappear, the DOM tree shows that "#shadow-root" node no longer has any child node, effectively making my SVG icons nowhere to be found.

Before disappearing:
[image]

After disappearing:
[image]

It is heart-breaking to see my lovely SVG icons suddenly disappear...

Please advise!

-----EDIT-----
Here is the code for the component that I am using to insert SVG icons:

```
import React from "react";

const Icon = ({ name }) => (
  <svg>
    <use xlinkHref={`img/icons/sprite.svg#icon-${name}`} />
  </svg>
);
export default Icon;
```

Comment: Can you post some code ?

Comment: @RagulParani just added the code for my Icon component!

Comment: @xavascript did you ever figure this out?

Comment: I was facing the same issue in my project. You are using SVG sprite which gets the problem in react. Because sprite SVG handle by browser shadow dom and react has it own V-DOM. You should directly use SVG code or import it in img tag. SVG sprite also get problem in some browsers.

Answer (score 2):

you can try another ways to include your SVG. I mentione three possibilities:

1. Use the .svg file as an img src, as we can see in create-react-app:

```
    import logo from './logo.svg';

    render() {...
          <img src={logo} className="App-logo" alt="logo" />
          ...}
```

2. Use svg-inline-react. For more info check [here](https://www.npmjs.com/package/svg-inline-react) :

```
    import InlineSVG from 'svg-inline-react';

    const svgSource = `<svg xmlns="......</svg>`;
    <InlineSVG src={svgSource} />
```

3. Convert the SVG into base64 and set it in the background image of your button.

Good luck.

Comment: I would recommend the first option suggested here.

Answer (score 0):

You can build the SVG element yourself. You can let React build the empty `<svg>` element, then manually insert a `<use>` element using a ref and an effect:

```
const Icon = React.memo(({ url }) => {
  const [svgNode, setSvgNode] = React.useState(null);

  React.useLayoutEffect(() => {
    if (svgNode === null) {
      return;
    }

    const useNode = document.createElementNS("http://www.w3.org/2000/svg", "use");
    useNode.setAttributeNS("http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink", "href", url);
    svgNode.appendChild(useNode);

    return () => {
      useNode.remove();
    };
  }, [type, svgNode]);

  return <svg ref={setSvgNode} />;
});
```

Based on [this implementation](https://github.com/googleanalytics/ga-dev-tools/blob/8af76bdccc6fa1ae42bf57eb7948b64787aac955/src/javascript/components/icon.tsx).